# Xcode 5 affects the deployment target of application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I built an application in an older version of Xcode, and once I rebuilt the application in Xcode 5 there were quite a few issues. One the biggest issues being that the status bar no longer displayed, and because of that the images were offset by 20px. How can I restore the project to it's original look in xCode 5?

Comment: Adjust all of your views so they start at `x:0 y:20`?  XCode 5 even has a default snap-to guide at `y 20px`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use xib to build your interface,you can rebuild it in storyboard,
however,you can reset your frame,in your appdeletage.m  reset your self.window.view'frame